# Create a multi dimensional array from form fields

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a multi dimensional array from form fields that I can loop through with jQuery and perform some calculations on the fly.

The form has an add attendee/remove attendee option and each attendee has 3 inputs so I am trying to create an array like so with the field names

```
attendees[0][name] = 'Name'
attendees[0][email] = 'Email'
attendees[0][type] = 'Normal'
```

I am using the following in jQuery to collect this array on the change event of the inputs within the form.

```
var values = $("input[name='attendees[]']").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
console.log(values);
```

The `alert` is just so I know that it is working but as you can see from my fiddle, regardless of what is in the attendee fields the array is always empty.

https://jsfiddle.net/b84s07x4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this quite simply by using `map()` on the `tbody tr` elements, instead of the first input in each row, and then using `find()` to get the required form elements.

You can also simplify the selector by placing a `class` on the form elements to read, otherwise you have to hack together a selector string using a name attribute which then has to escape the quotes contained within it. That becomes messy quickly.

Try this:

```
function calculate() {
    var attendees = $('.attendee-table > tbody > tr').map(function() {
        return  {
            name: $(this).find('.attendee-name').val(),
            email: $(this).find('.attendee-email').val(),
            type: $(this).find('.attendee-type').val()
        }
    }).get();
    console.log(attendees);
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/b84s07x4/4/)

Comment: This seems to do partly what I require but when removing an attendee the second object is still there.  Also the attendee type is not defined on any subsequent attendees bar the first one.

Comment: The problem with type was my mistake I missed a quote in the HTML string.  Also note that you'll need to call `calculate()` again in the removal event handler if you want to update the object at that point too. Here's another fiddle with both of those issues addressed: https://jsfiddle.net/b84s07x4/4/

Comment: No problem, glad to help. You can do that by clicking the green tick to the left